# Oracle SQL: Trouble Writing a Union Statement

Tags: sql, oracle

I've been a student of sql for the last 7 weeks and am having difficulty with unions.
I have a scenario in which I have to list the books a customer has bought but I can't duplicate the book titles in the query results.  In other words I need to drop the duplicates using a union.  Furthermore, I can't retrieve the books based on the customer# as I have to use their name as it is in the customer table.
I've been able to write a join that gets all the data I'm looking for but I don't know how to turn what I have into an union.

Here's my SQL:

```
select b.title, c.lastname, c.firstname
from customers c join orders o using (customer#)
    join orderitems oi using (order#)
    join books b using (isbn)
where c.lastname = 'LUCAS' and firstname = 'JAKE';
```

Here's the ERD:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8b6vo.png)

I appreciate any help someone could provide.

Comment: Can you give expected output?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use union to remove duplicates.

You should start by generating a list of unique titles which match your requirements.

```
SELECT DISTINCT b.title
FROM customers c 
JOIN orders o USING (customer#) 
JOIN orderitems oi USING (order#) 
JOIN books b USING (isbn) 
where c.lastname = 'LUCAS' AND firstname = 'JAKE'
```

And then join this back to the customer table to get your customer first and last names.

```
SELECT titles.title, c.lastname, c.firstname 
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT b.title
    FROM customers c 
    JOIN orders o USING (customer#) 
    JOIN orderitems oi USING (order#) 
    JOIN books b USING (isbn) 
    where c.lastname = 'LUCAS' AND firstname = 'JAKE'
) titles
LEFT JOIN customers c USING (customer#)
```